# c# how do i ask the user to press any keys to exit when they enter an invalid input

Tags: c#

I don't know how to ask user to press any keys to exit when they enter an invalid input.

Whenever i try to put `Console.ReadKey`(), the program just keeps on going. I don't know how to make it stop when user did not put a valid input.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

Here's the code

```
 /* Variable */

        int height = 0;                // stores user's height input
        int weight = 0;               // stores user's weight input
        const int factorBMI = 703;        // stores user's constant bmi which is 703
        double bmi = 0.0;                // stores user's calculated bmi
        /* User's Input */
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************************************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine(" Please enter the person's height in inches:");                                         // Ask user to enter their height in inches
        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out height))
            Convert.ToDecimal(height);
        if (height > 120)                                                                                        // Print an error message stating that if user's input is over 120 then an error pops
            Console.Write("\n height should be less than 120 inches, please press any key to exit:");
        if (height < 5)                                                                                          // Print an error message stating that if user's input is less than 5 then an error pops
            Console.Write("\n height should be greater than 5 inches and if you entered a letter, \n please enter a number next time:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\n Please enter the person's weight pounds:");                                       // Ask user to enter their weight in pounds
        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out weight))
            Convert.ToDecimal(weight);
        if (weight >= 999)                                                                                     // Print an error message if the user's input is more than 999 lbs
            Console.Write("\n weight should be less than 999 pounds, please exit the application");
        if (weight <= 0.5)                                                                                    // Print an error message if the user's input is less than 0.5 lbs
            Console.Write("\n weight should be greater than 0.5, \n if you did not enter a number, please enter a number next time:\n");

        /* Processing */

        bmi = Math.Round(weight / Math.Pow(height, 2) * factorBMI, 1);                                         // Calculates the user's BMI based on their height and weight input

        /* Output */
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************************************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("\n the BMI for a " + height + "\" tall person who weighs: " + weight + "lb. is " + bmi); // Print user's height, weight and calculated BMI
        if (bmi < 16)                                                                                              // If BMI is less than 16 then print the message
            Console.WriteLine("\n base on your BMI you are severly underweight");
        else if (bmi <= 18)                                                                                        // If BMI is less than 18 then print the message
            Console.WriteLine("\n base on your BMI you are underweight");
        else if (bmi <= 25)                                                                                       // If BMI is less than 25 then print the message
            Console.WriteLine("\n base on your BMI you are healthy");
        else if (bmi <= 30)                                                                                      // If BMI is less than 30 then print the message
            Console.WriteLine("\n base on your BMI you are overweight");
        else if (bmi > 30)                                                                                      // If BMI is more than 30 then print the message
            Console.WriteLine("\n base on your BMI you are obese");

        /* Exit  */

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n Thanks for using our program, you may now exit this program by presing any key:");// Print message telling the user to press any keys to exit application
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: if the user need only press "any key" to exit, how can they provide invalid input to the console? 

Copy and Paste your code directly into the question.  Outline what you are trying to do, what the unwanted behavior is, and anything you have tried up to this point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an else branch to your if (Int32.TryParse ...) statements like here:

```
if (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out height))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number"); //etc.
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

From your other error-outputs make blocks like here

```
if (height > 120)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your text");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, one more question though. How come whenever i try to input a decimal, it prompts the writeline and exits the application?

Comment: @ChowLife Maybe this decimal cannot be converted into Int32?

Comment: Perhaps, if you expect a decimal input, you should better use decimal.TryParse instead of Int32.TryParse. Then you can save the conversion. I edited my code example. May also be that double instead of decimal gives you enough precision for your purpose, but that must be your decision.